# copy rotation not working properly after joining two armatures together

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints, pose-mode

So I created a robot hand and I rigged the fingers with separate armatures using limit rotation and copy rotation constraints and it worked. After the fact I created the rest of the robot and started to create a single armature to control the whole robot, so I unparented the objects in my fingers and then joined those bones into the one armature. After I reparented the objects to the bones, it's no longer curling like it used to even with all the same constraints and parenting. Instead of curling this is the effect I'm getting.[image] All the bones are seemingly properly parented so I don't know why I'm getting this. What could be the problem? should I just start the finger bones from scratch? Just to add, it seems there's also a separate problem with the thumb after I unparented the the objects they moved slightly even though I also used keep transformation and those bones wont line up even after realigning them in edit mode, the adjustment doesn't apply in object mode or pose mode like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm no expert but I guess this is some kind of bug that when you join two armatures together, constraints will no longer do the same thing as when the armatures were apart. The part in my question where the thumb bones would no longer line up even after fixing them in edit mode is probably part of the same issue of joining two armatures together. To fix this I created a new set of bones in the place the added armature bones were and added the same constraints so now when I rotate my robot finger, it actually curls again like so. [image] This was all done in in blender 3.3.2 LTS and hopefully will get smoothed out in future versions.